My button is not moving with my Icon | Flutter | Dart

I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter app where I'm trying to add padding to an IconButton in the AppBar. However, when I add padding to the IconButton, the icon moves to the right, but the button stays in the same place. I want the icon to remain in its original position while adding padding to the button. Here is a code:


   `leading: Padding(
         padding:
             const EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0), 
         child: IconButton(
           icon: const Icon(
             Icons.menu,
             color: Colors.white,
           ),
           onPressed: () {},
         ),
       ),
       actions: [
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
               right: 45.0), 
           child: IconButton(
             onPressed: () {},
             icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.white),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
`

I've tried wrapping the IconButton with a Container and applying padding to it, but the issue persists. How can I add padding to the IconButton without moving the icon itself? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

what do you expect? not moving where?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That's because leading have limited space in your AppBar widget. You can use Row to align actions in your AppBar, something like this:
AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      actions: [
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 45.0), // устанавливаем отступ слева
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.menu,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('123');
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: 45.0), // устанавливаем отступ справа
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon:
                      const Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),

Hope this will help
